# Trouble using chrome frame

Tags: html, google-chrome, google-chrome-frame

I detect if a user has chrome frame by placing this in teh body of my page:

```
<script type="text/javascript"
src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/chrome-frame/1/CFInstall.min.js"> </script>

<div id="placeholder"></div>

<script>
 CFInstall.check({
    node: "placeholder",
destination: "http://www.waikiki.com"
  });
</script>
```

In the header of my boilerplate page I have:

```
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="chrome=1">
```

I managed to get the site to prompt me to install chrome frame, which I did, but the page still renders with IE errors, any ideas why?

Using IE7.

Comment: What do you mean, "renders in IE and not Chrome"?  As far as Chrome frame goes, it is virtually undetectable by the user whether the page is in IE or using Chrome frame.  The browser will not look like Chrome while using the Chrome frame.

Comment: The IE7 errors are still there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can tell if the page is using chrome frame by right clicking on the page. If the context menu lists "About Chrome Frame.." it's rendering the page via chrome frame plugin.

Also you need to call CFInstall.check after the body is loaded.